# sql table design to fetch records with multiple inclusion and exclusion conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

We want to select customers based on following parameters i.e. customer should be in:

1. specific city i.e. cityId=1,2,3...
2. specific customerId should be excluded i.e. customerId=33,2323,34534...
3. specific age i.e. 5 years, 7 years, 72 years...

This inclusion & exclusion list can be any long.

How should we design database for this:

1. Create separate table 'customerInclusionCities' for these inclusion cities and do like:

select * from customers where cityId in (select cityId from customerInclusionCities)

Some we do for age, create table 'customerEligibleAge' with all entries of eligible age entries:

i.e. `select * from customers where age in (select age from customerEligibleAge`)

and Create separate table 'customerIdToBeExcluded' for excluding customers:

i.e. `select * from customers where customerId not in (select customerId from customerIdToBeExcluded`)

OR

2. Create One table with Category and Ids.
   i.e. Category1 for cities, Category2 for CustomerIds to be excluded.

Which approach is better, creating one table for these parameters OR creating separate tables for each list i.e. age, customerId, city?

Comment: Have you ever explored buildng a star schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` can be very slow.  Do your query as a single `SELECT` without subqueries.  I assume all 3 columns are in the same table?  (If not, that adds complexity.)  The `WHERE` clause will probably have 3 `IN ( constants )` clauses:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE cityId IN (1,2,3...)
      AND customerId NOT IN (33,2323,34534...)
      AND age IN (5, 7, 72)
```

Have (at least):

```
INDEX(cityId),
INDEX(age)
```

(Negated things are unlikely to be able to use an index.)

The query will use one of the indexes; having both will give the Optimizer a choice of which it thinks is better.

**Or...**

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM customers AS c
    JOIN cityEligible AS b  ON b.city = c.city
    JOIN customerEligibleAge AS ce  ON c.age = ce.age
    LEFT JOIN customerIdToBeExcluded AS ex ON c.customerId = ex.customerId
    WHERE ex.customerId IS NULL
```

Suggested indexes (probably as `PRIMARY KEY`):

```
customers: (city)
customerEligibleAge: (age)
customerIdToBeExcluded: (customerId)
```

In order to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any of the queries actually work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we want this list of cityIds, customerIds,age to be configurable and so we would keep them in tables and not write them directly in SP.

Comment: What is your client language?

Comment: we are using mysql

Comment: PHP?  Java?  No code?  If no code, where does the long list of customerIDs come from?

Comment: It is C# that calls this SP.

Comment: If they are in tables, please rewrite the query so that it joins to the config tables that have the values.  In the case of 'exclusion', use `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL`.  Maybe I will take a crack at it tomorrow.  (Or someone else will step in.)

Comment: These can be flag in existing tables(city,customer) too but i don't want to keep them there since this is information is temporary and it may go off after 3-4 months.

Comment: I added another approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the database only that operation, I recommend to use the first solution. Also the first solution is very simple to deploy.

The second solution fills up with junk the DB.